# https certificate is no longer valid

Tags: ios, ssl, https

I'm using an API that https and for some days my application does not work because the certificate is no longer valid api and my lib `afnetworking` can not retrieved the information. how to make the lib `afnetworking` ssl accept that is not valid

thank you.

Comment: Why would you want to do that, just update you SSL certificate. If you disable the SSL check then any certificate can be used and a man in the middle attack will be possible.

Comment: I can not update the certificate because it is not my site

Comment: AFSecurityPolicy *sec=[[AFSecurityPolicy alloc] init];
[sec setAllowInvalidCertificates:YES];
operation.securityPolicy=sec;